# Parsing XML from webpage

Tags: java, xml, parsing

If I copy and paste the xml from this site into a xml file I can parse it with java

http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=8397709210207872&q=java&l=austin%2C+tx&sort&radius&st&jt&start&limit&fromage&filter&latlong=1&chnl&userip=1.2.3.4&v=2

However, I want to parse it directly from a webpage if possible!

Here's my current code:

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder; 
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

  public class XMLParser {

public void readXML(String parse) {
    File xml = new File(parse);
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder;
    try {
        dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xml);
 //         System.out.println("Root element :"
 //                 + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("result");

        System.out.println("----------------------------");

        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

 //             System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + 
     nNode.getNodeName());

            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                System.out.println("job title : "
                        + 
 eElement.getElementsByTagName("jobtitle").item(0)
                        .getTextContent());;
                System.out.println("Company: "
                        + 
  eElement.getElementsByTagName("company")

 .item(0).getTextContent());
                System.out.println("City : "
                        + 
  eElement.getElementsByTagName("city").item(0)
                                .getTextContent());
                System.out.println("State : "
                        + 
eElement.getElementsByTagName("state").item(0)
                                .getTextContent());
                System.out.println("Country : "
                        + 
eElement.getElementsByTagName("country").item(0)
                                .getTextContent());
                System.out.println("Date posted : "
                        + 
     eElement.getElementsByTagName("date").item(0)
                                .getTextContent());
                System.out.println("Job summary : "
                        + 
    eElement.getElementsByTagName("snippet").item(0)
                                .getTextContent());
                System.out.println("Latitude : "
                        +      
 eElement.getElementsByTagName("latitude").item(0).getTextContent());
                System.out.println("longitude : "
                        +     
eElement.getElementsByTagName("longitude").item(0).getTextContent());

            }
        }

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new XMLParser().readXML("test.xml");
}
 }
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Give it the URI instead of the XML. It will download it for you.

Document doc = dBuilder.parse(uriString)

Answer (score 1):

Please find the code snippet like this

```
String url = "http://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=8397709210207872&q=java&l=austin%2C+tx&sort&radius&st&jt&start&limit&fromage&filter&latlong=1&chnl&userip=1.2.3.4&v=2";

try
{
  DocumentBuilderFactory f = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  DocumentBuilder b = f.newDocumentBuilder();
  Document doc = b.parse(url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's how I parsed data directly from url http://www.nbp.pl/kursy/xml/+something

```
static class Kurs {
    public float kurs_sprzedazy;
    public float kurs_kupna;
}

private static DocumentBuilder dBuilder;

private static Kurs getData(String filename, String currency) throws Exception {
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse("http://www.nbp.pl/kursy/xml/"+filename+".xml");

    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("pozycja");

    for(int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
        Element nNode = (Element)nList.item(i);
        if(nNode.getElementsByTagName("kod_waluty").item(0).getTextContent().equals(currency)) {
            Kurs kurs = new Kurs();
            String data = nNode.getElementsByTagName("kurs_sprzedazy").item(0).getTextContent();
            data = data.replace(',', '.'); 
            kurs.kurs_sprzedazy = Float.parseFloat(data);
            data = nNode.getElementsByTagName("kurs_kupna").item(0).getTextContent();
            data = data.replace(',', '.');
            kurs.kurs_kupna = Float.parseFloat(data);
            return kurs;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```